# Tint attribute causes pixelation on a vector graphic

Tags: android, vector-graphics

Here is a vector graphic I imported into Android Studio: 
[image: Vector without pixelization]

When I add the `android:tint="@color/exampleColor"` attribute, the vector gets pixelated:
[image: Vector with pixelization]

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Changing scaleType to fitXY fixes the pixelization, but stretches the image:
[image: Vector without pixelization, but stretched]

Comment: DId you try adding the attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to the ImageView?

Comment: @MikiMints That fixes the pixelization, but it stretches the image.

Comment: How about using scaleType="center" instead? Maybe that would fix both issues?